# Oracle to_timestamp produces error

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I am trying to get a value of time-stamp column using jdbc driver. The following query works like a charm :

```
to_char(update_date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF9 TZR') update_date
```

However, instead of to_char, I need timestamp values and if I use the following query in my select statemnt, it gives

> OTA-01821-Date format not recognized

error. please can someone help?

```
to_timestamp(update_date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF9 TZR') update_date
```

Comment: What is the data type of column `update_date`.  If it is a `timestamp` (which it seems it should be) then there is no need to convert it at all.

Comment: Try `To_timestamp(To_char(update_date,'Format'),'Format')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate cause of the error is the TZR part of the format mask, which isn't valid for a plain timestamp. You could either convert to a timestamp *with time zone* [with a different function](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions230.htm):

```
to_timestamp_tz(update_date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF9 TZR')
```

or omit the time zone:

```
to_timestamp(update_date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF9')
```

But as `uodate_date` is already a timestamp (with [local] time zone), you are implicitly converting it to a string using [your session's `NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT` setting](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-A340C735-BA5A-4704-B24C-AC2C2380BA9E.htm#REFRN10132), before explicitly converting that string back to a timestamp (with or without time zone).

At best this is pointless, but if your NLS setting doesn't match the explicit format you use then it will give a different error or incorrect results.

If you want a timestamp value from Java then don't do any conversion - just select the original `update_date` column, and use the JDBC `getTimestamp()` to retrieve it.

Comment: Thanks! My timestamp column is in the format 17-07-14 08:40:47.000000000 UTC. What should I use for this?

Comment: If the data type of the column is timestamp with (possibly local) time zone then it does not have any intrinsic format. Your client is using your NLS setting to display it like that. You do not need to convert it at all.